# round,ceiling 2 decimal points

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, ceil

I want to round up some figures that have 2 decimals points to 1.
However, I always want it to round 1
examples of the list of figures in column `amount`

```
140.08 = 140.1
141.63 = 141.7
```

if I use round(141.63,1) it equals 142.6, but I want all the decimal points to round up, similar to the ceiling function. I want 141.7

Any help would be great?

thanks
Don

Comment: simply do for one - select ROUND('140.08', 1).

Comment: you should do one thing, whatever result you have, just pass it in ' ' by using ROUND (' ', 1).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can try this.

```
select ceiling(141.63 * 10) / 10.0 ,
       ceiling(140.08 * 10) / 10.0
```

Result

```
141.700000                              
140.100000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Cheers Don

Comment: A bit weird that Round doesn't allow to chose rounding up/down, and Celing/Floor don't allow decimal places. Great work around.